# How to create a terminal emulator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, terminal, terminal-emulator

Getting bored with the traditional `cmd` on windows, so wanted to build one myself. Any tutorial, library, etc would help.

Thanks in advance! `:)`

Comment: Your are confusing the pseudo-terminal (the "separate window") with the shell itself (which IS "a CLI app with interactive prompt").

Comment: you can execute cmd-commands with os.system("command"), but I dont know whether that is what you want. You want a window like cmd for system commands, but written in Python, right? Or do I understand something wrong here?

Comment: Pretty much every app ever is a cli app, just some hide the window from the user and create their own gui. If you are looking to make a GUI to take user input and spit out repsonses, I'd look into Tkinter first then progress to something like Qt5. If you are looking to develop  your own "language" you'll need to start off with a grammar (using something like [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)) to define how your language will be written. From there you'll have to do a ton more research on implementation, but that's generally the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *shell* in the sense of the CLI command interpretor (which are bash or cmd.exe) can be OS independant. The window holding it will have to either depend on a GUI framework (and could be more less OS independant) or directly use an special OS facility. For example on Windows executable can be tagged as GUI processes and have to provide a Windows interface or as *console* processes. In that latter case, the system automatically provides them with a *console* system object (which is erroneously called cmd windows) connected to the Stdin, Stdout and Stderr streams.

In Unix or Linux, you can find a number of *terminal emulators* (the `xterm` family and derivatives like `konsole`) that by default host the standard shell of the user but can host any other command interpretor.

The interpretor will be easy to write in Python - even if a parser like PLY could help - , and will still be easy to install in a console on terminal emulator. If you need to build a GUI to host it, you will have to use a Python GUI framework like tkinter (standard), PyQt, wxWindows, PyGTK, Kivy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make your own functions, or use the module os to use normal commands. For what I understand from your question, this is the best answer I can make.

```
while True:
    command = str(input("Command: "))
    if command == "test":
        #do Something
    elif command == "another thing":
        #do other thing
```

using the while True so it will keep asking you again and again after each command